# Advice on setup to run Shiny Server (requires Linux) for R web apps when we have a Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise Server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-server-2008-r2, virtualization

I am a rookie when it comes to servers, but I have nonetheless been the one asked to get [Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/) up and running for web applications in the open-source statistics and computing environment R at my office.  Shiny requires a Linux server ("You can also deploy Shiny applications over the web...You’ll need a Linux server and our Shiny Server software..."), but we have a 64-bit Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise server.  From the reading I've done so far, it seems like we could use free options such as VMWare Server or Microsoft Virtual Server to run Linux and then run Shiny on Linux.  Would that approach make sense?  If so, I am also wondering if we could use Ubuntu Server as our Linux Server OS in this case and, if the answer is yes, whether you have found 12.04.3 or 13.04 to be the more stable Ubuntu version of the two.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into using [Microsoft Hyper-V](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448604.aspx) to host your Virtual Machine on.

I would also recommend using [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/) over Ubuntu for a stable server operating system.

Comment: Great, thanks for the suggestions, @dirt!  We'll give it a try.  Unfortunately, my rep points are so low (actually, I only have 1 point at the moment) that I cannot upvote your comment.